# cannot install Genymotion on Windows 8

Tags: android, genymotion

In order to run Genymotion plugin on android studio I need to install Genymotion in my pc but my windows 8 tells source is curropted everytime 
is my download linkhttps://www.genymotion.com of Genymotion setup file wrong? or I am missing something
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accroding to the Official Genymotion FAQ,

> **My installer doesn't start. How can I check its integrity?**
>
> Your installer may be corrupted. To check the installer integrity,
>   follow this procedure:
>
> 1. Go to the [Download](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) page.
> 2. Copy the checksum corresponding to the version of the installer you've downloaded.
> 3. Make sure that the checksum of your installer is identical. The method depends on your operating system:
>
> A.  If needed, install FCIV, as detailed in this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889768).
>
> B. In a command prompt, run the following command: `FCIV -sha1
>   <Genymotion-installer-path>/genymotion-<version-number>.exe`